# What does the phrase "that we does not receive payment for" mean?

Tags: meaning

> Qualifying booking excludes a travel booking canceled by the traveler,
>   resulting from fraudulent or other illegal activity, or that **we does
>   not** receive payment for.

What does "that we does not receive payment for" mean? To which part does this phrase apply?

I read it from a T&C article, and I can't find the link where I read it.

Comment: 'We does not' is an error, and should be 'we do not'.

Comment: Please do not edit your question in such as way as to invalidate existing answers. I have rolled back your edit to replace the original (incorrect) *does*. (Which the answer addresses.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an error in the sentence: instead of "we does not," it should be "we do not":

> Qualifying booking excludes a travel booking canceled by the traveler,
>   resulting from fraudulent or other illegal activity, or that **we do
>   not** receive payment for.

"We do not receive payment" refers to any booking they do not receive payment for.

Comment: You ought to change the title too.

Comment: Which title...?

Comment: At the top, in big letters, it says **What does the phrase “that we does not receive payment for” mean?**

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Nothing about the incorrect word should be changed In the question itself *after an answer is given*. It's fine to change the answer (if it's wrong) but not the title of the question. (Although, admittedly, there may have been comments here that have since been deleted which make the existing comments unclear.)